# share variable between processes in Python

Tags: python, process, ipc

Using python, how do I share a global variable.

I have main process which calls processA

processA keeps updating the variable and I need that information in the main process.

How is that possible ?

Comment: we need more context.   when you say process calls another process.   what mechanisms are being used (what python functions, command, etc) ?   That will help determine a useful answer for you.

Comment: I am using something like this "multiprocessing.Process(target=testservice,
                                           args=(params,))

Comment: You need to provide way more details. Processes **do not share state**, you need to use one of the various approaches detailed in the [`multiprocessing` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). Have you read that?